# Initialise a variable to its own undefined value

Tags: c

In C, does initialising a variable to it's own value make sense? If yes, what for?

Allow me to elaborate. In Git sources there are some examples of initialising a variable to it's own undefined value, as seen in [transport.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f84667def209e4a84e37e8488a08e9eca3f208c1/transport.c#L109) or  [wt-status.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f84667def209e4a84e37e8488a08e9eca3f208c1/wt-status.c#L267). I removed assignments from those declarations and run tests. Seeing no regressions, I thought that those assignments were redundant.

On the other hand, I did some simple tests with GCC 4.6 and Clang 2.9.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  printf("print to increase probability of registers being non-zero\n");
  int status = status;
  return printf("%i\n", status);
}
```

Compiling with `-Wall -std=c99` and various `-O` levels prints no warnings and shows that `status == 0`. Clang with a non-zero optimisation level prints some garbage values though. It makes me infer that results of such expressions are undefined.

I can imagine that such assignment can suppress an *uninitialised variable* warning, but it's not the case for the examples taken from Git. Removing assignments doesn't introduce any warnings.

Are such assignments an undefined behaviour? If not, what do you use them for?

---

I've suggested the change on the Git mailing list. [Here's what I've learned](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/185969).

Comment: Maybe the examples in git don't suppress an uninitialized variable warning for *your* system, but on systems that other developers regularly use.  With GCC, uninitialized variable warnings are affected by optimization flags, and Clang produces a fairly different set of warnings even though it is a "drop-in replacement" for GCC.

Comment: I would initialize such variables to 0 (or -1) rather than drop the initialization altogether.  Someone added the code for a purpose; I can respect the purpose even though I find the mechanism used odd.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, not only is it odd, on platforms with trap representations this yields undefined behavior.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This compiles because **Standard C99 §6.2.1/7** says:

> Any identifier that is not a structure, union, or enumeration tag "has scope that begins just after the completion of its declarator." The declarator is followed by the initializer.

However, value of `status` is **Indeterminate**. And you cannot rely on it being initialized to something meaningful.

**How does it work?**
`int status` creates an space for the variable to exist on the stack(local storage) which is then further read to perform `status = status`, `status` might get initialized to any value that was present in the stack frame.

**How can you guard against such self Initialization?**
gcc provides a specific setting to detect self Initializations and report them as errors:

> -Werror=uninitialized -Winit-self

**Why is it used in this code?**
The only reason I can think it is being used in the said code is to suppress the unused variable warning for ex: In `transport.c`, if the control never goes inside the `while` loop then in that control flow `cmp` will be unused and the compiler must be generating a warning for it. Same scenario seems to be with `status` variable in `wt-status.c`

Comment: I think the idea is not to suppress the 'unused variable' warning (you can do that more simply by deleting the unused variable), but the '(sometimes) used before initialized' warning.  It's a minor detail - it does not alter the validity of the main part of your answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Your comment is spot on.I messed that bit in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For me the only reason of such self-assigning initialization is to avoid a warning.

In the case of your `transport.c`, I don't even understand why it is useful. I would have left  `cmp` uninitialized.

My own habit (at least in C) is to initialize all the variables, usually to 0. The compiler will optimize unneeded initialization, and having all variables initialized makes debugging easier.

There is a case when I want a variable to remain uninitialized, and I might self-assign it: random seeds:

```
 unsigned myseed = myseed;
 srand(myseed);
```

Comment: But are there any run-time analysis tools that would notice that `cmp` is read when it still holds uninitialized bytes? The logic should force `cmp` to be assigned something in the `while` before it is read in the `if` so you want the compiler to "shut up because the human knows what he's doing" but `int cmp = 0` would defeat the run-time analysis and possibly hide a bug.

Comment: You mean *compile-time* not *run-time* analysis?? But I don't understand your comment.

Comment: `int cmp = cmp` might be enough to fool the compiler into thinking that `cmp` is always assigned before being read so compile-time warnings would be suppressed. But, if you watch the bytes at run-time then `int cmp = cmp` still leaves `cmp` full of junk until the `while` loop's condition initializes it; so, if the logic is flawed and the `if` can read `cmp` without the `while` assigning it a value then that could be detected when `int cmp = cmp` is used. Using `int cmp = 0` would suppress both possible warnings.

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS X 10.7.2, I tried this example - with the result shown...

```
$ cat x3.c
#include <stdio.h>

int status = -7;

int main()
{
    printf("status = %d\n", status);
    int status = status;
    printf("status = %d\n", status);
    return 0;
}
$ make x3
gcc -O -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra  x3.c -o x3  
$ ./x3
status = -7
status = 1787486824
$
```

The stack space where the local `status` in `main()` has been used by `printf()` so the self-initialization copies garbage around.

Answer (score 0):

I think `status = status` doesn't change the value of `status` (compared to `int status;`). I think it is used to suppress the `unused variable` warning.