# What is the expected output of initializing a variable to itself?

Tags: c

```
int abc = abc;
printf ("%d",abc);
```

What does initializing a variable to itself do? My compiler gives the output `0` .

Hovewer, a source that I can't trust says "The address of the variable `abc` will be printed.". But it doesn't give a reason, and I am confused by this explanation because we are using the format specifier `"%d"`.

Comment: `abc` is unitialized.  You're getting `0` but it could be anything (garbage).

Comment: easy-to-find dupe of [What's the behavior of an uninitialized variable used as its own initializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200465/whats-the-behavior-of-an-uninitialized-variable-used-as-its-own-initializer)

Comment: And why is it valid? How is it even compiled?

Comment: Research "undefined behaviour". That, like the question itself, is well discussed already.

Comment: It's not a compilation (syntactical) error.  It's a logic error.  C doesn't check for logic errors and assumes the programmer knows what they're doing.

Comment: The address of `abc` is `&abc`.

Comment: Another dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284309/initialise-a-variable-to-its-own-undefined-value

Comment: I actually surfed in stack overflow for this but didn't know the term of "uninitialized" so I asked this question, sorry.

Comment: "expected output of initializing a variable to itself?" -- it depends on the kind of variable: `unsigned char` or not, `register` or not.